# Как избавиться от непонятного пробела?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как избавиться от пробелов между родительским блоком и дочерним. Я думаю связано это с округлением пикселей браузера и масштабированием, т.к. при значении `border` от `1` до `3` эти пробелы появляются с разных сторон, но когда я меняю на `4`, то пробел исчезает.

Пробелы при `border` равному `3px`:

[image: Пробелы]

Исходный код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.t1 {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.t2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="t1">
  <div class="t2">Test</div>
</div>
```

Должно же быть какое-то универсальное решение, я понимаю, что могу сделать `border` у дочернего блока, но этот пример максимально упрощен по сравнению с реальным кодом, где мне нужен `border` именно у родительского элемента. Может какие-то начальные значения, которые устанавливает браузер, нужно убрать. Хотя я пробовал вставлять `reset.css`

Comment: у меня ваша верстка без пробела отобразилась с 3px. так что либо "максимально упрощен" зря ибо где-то там виновник, либо дело в браузере что сильно врятли. короче, код в студию.

Comment: @puffleeck странно, почему все кто как-то откликался, игнорируют тот факт, что проблема именно в том коде, который я и выложил :) Ну правда, я прямо сейчас нажимаю на "Выполнить код", прямо в вопросе, и наблюдаю эту ошибку. Я же не дурак, чтобы упростить код, не проверив правильно ли он работает в упрощенном виде. Это связано с браузером я уверен на 99%, а конкретней с тем, что я написал в вопросе. У меня этой проблемы при `3px` так же может не быть, если я например изменю масштаб. Вот только что изменил масштаб со `100%` до `110%` и проблема исчезла.

Comment: @Bonifacy Я тебе написал, что проблема в отрисовке браузера, а не в коде, предложил два решения и прислал ссылку на английский stackoverflow с такой же проблемой, что тебя не устраивает?

Comment: @DanilApsadikov в чем проблема я и до вас догадывался. Я хотел бы найти универсальное решение, а не частное. Лично я в процессе поиска, если мои поиски увенчаются неудачей, то я или напишу свой полный ответ, или так и быть выберу ваш, хотя то, что вы предложили я еще давно отбросил.

Comment: @Bonifacy как вариант сделать для дочернего элемента margin: -0.5px; width: calc(100% + 1px);

Comment: @DanilApsadikov хорошая идея, но я нашел как мне кажется лучше. Использовать вместо `border` `box-shadow`, как я не менял отступы, масштаб и т.д. не получилось получить этот злосчастный пробел. Я точно не знаю, как это работает. Надо будет посмотреть про работу `box-shadow`

Comment: Оригинальное решение

Answer (score -2):

Код правильный, ошибка в отрисовке есть. Могу предложить сделать `background: pink` Не у t2, а t1

Comment: К сожалению, такой способ мне не подходит, т.к. по логике основного кода, при наведении на внутренний блок, у него должен меняться цвет заднего фона, и таких блоков будет несколько.

Comment: Можешь прочитать здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68861329/space-between-border-parent-div-and-child-divs Если коротко, то это связанно с тем, что браузер не точно вычисляет размеры элементов, и мною описанный способ является верным, по другому не получится

Comment: Я не спорю, что ваш способ сработает, но повторю еще раз, мне такой способ не подходит. Хорошо я сделаю задний фон у родительского блока, а что мне делать, когда я добавлю еще несколько дочерних, все это в виде списка, и при наведении мне нужно менять задний фон у дочернего элемента. Что я увижу тогда? Ту же полоску, только розового цвета. Я не верю, что нет другого способа решить эту проблему, т.к. я не понимаю, как я раньше ни разу не сталкивался с ней, хотя опыта не мало.

Comment: Тогда нужно более подробно описывать код. Можно убрать обводку у родителя и сделать рамку по бокам у дочерних элементов, а у первого и последнего добавить рамку сверху/снизу